# How can I use ::before pseudoclass to create a loading screen for its element?

Tags: html, css

I have the following markup for a container div that's somewhere in the middle of the page:

```
<div class="content">
   <div id="googleMap">...</div>
   <div id="someTable">...</div>
   <div id="doesntMatter>some other stuff</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use a pseudoclass to provide an "Loading..." overlay for the `<div class="content">`.  And then later, once the data is loaded, remove the overlay to reveal all the inner divs.

I am having trouble coding css for the pseudoclass so that it overlays the entire div.  If I set the position to absolute, it takes the entire screen.  With position=relative, it takes the smallest amount of screen.

```
.content:before {
  content: 'Loading...';
  text-align: center; 
  position: absolute;
}
```

The example is [here](https://codepen.io/FrankRizzo/pen/xWWVEE).  Am I going about this the wrong way?  Is the overlay even possible to achieve with a pseudoclass?

Comment: don't forget positon:relative on the parent element

Comment: like this : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrrVyr

Comment: You are trying to add a pseudo-element, not a pseudo-class. Your title shows `::before` which is a pseudo-element but your markup shows one colon which is a class. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before

Comment: Here is a slightly different approach: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rddKKx

Comment: @ThejakaMaldeniya I like it.  Very clean - going with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Position absolute definition: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

So you need the div.content positioned relative.

```css
.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
}

.content::before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3)
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: relative` to your parent class. The absolutely positioned element refers to the closest parent that has `position: relative` when it tries to position itself which you can think of being the body tag unless you specify it on a parent.